# kendo-ui mvc autocomplete does not display results

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I was able to get a working version using the js version [dojo autocomplate](http://dojo.telerik.com/@willtx111/oFolI/5) but I need it to work using the MVC version. I added `DataSourceRequest` in the controller as suggested below and changed a couple more items that got rid of the js error I was getting:

```
  //Fixed, added the schema definition
  Uncaught TypeError: e.slice is not a function
```

It appears to work as I trace it through the controller, which returns the expected json (below) but it doesn't finish wiring up as the spinner hangs and the results aren't displayed.

```
   {
   "Data": [{
    "EmployeeId": 2147483649,
    "EmployeeName": "Emily F Johnston",
    "Rating": 75.0,
    "LastAudited": null
   }, {
    "EmployeeId": 2147483687,
    "EmployeeName": "Joshua Smith",
    "Rating": 80.2,
    "LastAudited": null
  }, {
    "EmployeeId": 2147483656,
    "EmployeeName": "Thomas F Dunn",
    "Rating": 45.0,
    "LastAudited": "\/Date(1463893200000)\/"
  }, {
    "EmployeeId": 2147483660,
    "EmployeeName": "Marjon Christine Marik",
    "Rating": 88.0,
    "LastAudited": null
  }],
  "Total": 4,
  "AggregateResults": null,
  "Errors": null
 }
```

The controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeeLookup(string text, [DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var filter = request?.Filters.FirstOrDefault() as FilterDescriptor;
        var search = string.Empty;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            search = filter.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
        var employees = new List<EmployeeLookupResultEntryViewModel>();
        var results = _employeeService.EmployeeLookup(search);

        if (results == null)
            return Json(employees.ToDataSourceResult(request));

        return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

The autocomplete definition:

Also, I found this doco from Telerik that looks very similar to my use case [Telerik Custom Template](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete/template) but it lacks showing the controller methods so I can't verify how they wired it up.

```
   @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                .Name("Employees")
                .DataTextField("EmployeeName")
                .Placeholder("Search Employee")
                .Filter("contains")
                .IgnoreCase(true)
                .MinLength(3)
                .Delay(300)
                .HighlightFirst(true)
               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                .NoDataTemplate("Employee Not Found")
                .DataSource(dataSource =>
                {
                   dataSource.Custom()
                             .ServerFiltering(true)
                             .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
                             .Transport(transport =>
                             {
                                transport.Read("EmployeeLookup", "Employee", new {area = "Client"});
                             })
                            .Schema(schema => {schema.Data("Data");});
                    })
                   .HeaderTemplate("<div style=\"width: 400px;\" class=\"dropdown-header k-widget k-header\">" +
                               "<span>Id</span>" +
                                "<span>Name</span>" +
                                 "<span>Pwc Rating" +
                                  "<span>Last Audited</span>" +
                    "</div>")
                 .Template("<span  style=\"width: 50px;\">#: data.EmployeeId #</span><span class=\"cell\">#: data.EmployeeName #</span><span class=\"cell\">#: data.PwcRating #</span><span class=\"cell\">#: data.LastAudited #</span>")
        )
```

I seem to be missing some config setting in the html because the json/datasouce is being returned, similarly to what the documentation states...yet the widget can't wire it up.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled server filtering, which is significantly more complex than you've implemented

If you intended to enable this feature there are three things you need to do

1. Add Kendo ASP.NET MVC libraries to your project
2. Change your datasource type to be aspnetmvc-ajax:
3. Rework your action to use DataSourceRequest in your controller per this [example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). **The DataSourceRequest attribute is NOT optional**

   ```
   public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
   {
       return Json(productService.Read().ToDataSourceResult(request));
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found a telerik link that looks like what I'm after but they don't provide the controller I need to verify how they wired the lookup. I removed the sever-side filtering config but that's not enough. I'll try to implement what you suggest.

Comment: I implemented the DataSourceRequest, I can see the filter value coming through and the response is as expected yet the spinner never stops and the suggested values are not displayed (no js errors either).